# Global Consistency of Deletion in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The following snippet from [GCS docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques):

> Strong global consistency also extends to deletion (DELETE) operations on objects and update (PUT) operations that change existing object and bucket ACLs. If you delete an object and you receive a success response, an immediate attempt to download (GET) the object will result in a 404 Not Found status code. Likewise, if you change ACLs on an object or bucket and you receive a success response, the newly applied object or bucket ACLs are immediately available.

is perplexing, I thought that global consistency means I **won't** get a 404 Not Found error, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get a 404 error because the object no longer exists after the delete operation completes successfully. If it weren't for strong consistency, it would be possible to delete an object and then perform a GET on the object and get back the old, pre-deleted state of the object.